# SunSystems debugging

Tags: cobol, microfocus

please I am debugging cobol program on SunSystems 5.2.1 via MF Net Express 3.1.11 SP1. So I am on virtual machine with Windows XP.
But on debug when I am not quick enough I got this message: "The sunsystems server is unavailable. Since there are no remaining functions open SunSystems will now close down."
If I am debugging quick everything is going fine.
Please can anyone help? Is there any setting for that?
I found only in SUN root directory file SUN5.INI and there this option:
CCI-Time-Out=3000
I try to set this to 9000 but no change.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You have _a lot_ of `<br>` in your question. To me, this makes reading it unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: I don't think this is a COBOL question, Micro Focus or otherwise, unless it is your program coming to an end and closing the "window" before you are ready. A dummy `ACCEPT` statement can help with that. Otherwise look for a tag to describe your setup of the VM, if that seems to be your real problem.